# Electrostatics of conductors- edge effects

Tags: electrostatics

So I read somewhere that if you place a charge inside a cube the induced charge is distributed non-uniformly;its more concentrated on the edges and corners. And its in not just this case; I have also read directions stating, 'Ignore edge effects' while solving problems. Why are edges so susceptible to a high charge density?

Answer (score 0):

In a charged conductor where charges are free to move about, since the charges repel each other, they indeed tend to accumulate in corners or edges. The exact charge distribution is the one that maintains constant electrostatic potential within the conductor, and yields the correct total charge. However, this distribution is usually not easy to calculate by hand, except in the simplest geometries.